# Find Element Using Two Criteria in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to find an element in a table to firstly scrape the text/number and then, if it meets criteria, click on it.

Here's an example page: https://www.oddschecker.com/horse-racing/wolverhampton/20:30/winner.

To do this I need to locate the selection name in the table row (`class="diff-row evTabRow bc"`) and the book in the data cell (`data-bk="PP"`).

```
selection = 'Aramis Grey'
book = 'PP'
```

I'm new to selenium and can find the individual elements but don't know how to combine the criteria for different elements.

Edit:

The original link is no longer available but trying the suggestions using this link https://www.oddschecker.com/horse-racing/kempton/20:30/winner gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Oddschecker v5.py", line 42, in <module>
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class="diff-row evTabRow bc"][data-bname="Blue Beret"] [data-bk="WH"]'))).click()
  File "C:\Users\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 693, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 400, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 236, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <td class="bc bs oi" data-bk="WH" data-odig="4.33" data-o="10/3" data-hcap="" data-fodds="12.0" data-best-ew="false" data-best-wo="false" data-ew-denom="5" data-ew-places="4">...</td> is not clickable at point (762, 864). Other element would receive the click: <div class="_3g1ozk">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=94.0.4606.61)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x015CD403+2479107]
    Ordinal0 [0x01567D51+2063697]
    Ordinal0 [0x014720C8+1056968]
    Ordinal0 [0x014A2A59+1256025]
    Ordinal0 [0x014A0D7B+1248635]
    Ordinal0 [0x0149EB4D+1239885]
    Ordinal0 [0x0149D9FD+1235453]
    Ordinal0 [0x014933C7+1192903]
    Ordinal0 [0x014B5973+1333619]
    Ordinal0 [0x014931E6+1192422]
    Ordinal0 [0x014B5A5A+1333850]
    Ordinal0 [0x014C4CAF+1395887]
    Ordinal0 [0x014B583B+1333307]
    Ordinal0 [0x01491F94+1187732]
    Ordinal0 [0x01492DE9+1191401]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0174F3F6+1531734]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x017FE9AE+2249998]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x016539AB+501003]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x01652A29+497033]
    Ordinal0 [0x0156D11D+2085149]
    Ordinal0 [0x015711C8+2101704]
    Ordinal0 [0x01571302+2102018]
    Ordinal0 [0x0157AA71+2140785]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x74FC6A14+36]
    RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x7777AD8F+143]
    RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x7777AD5A+90]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There's a accept cookies button.
2. There's a modal pop up windows
3. There's a X pop up.
4. Use Explicit waits.

**Sample code :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://www.oddschecker.com/horse-racing/wolverhampton/20:30/winner")

try:
    print('When we have Want to be kept in the loop? Modal pop up')
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Not Now']/.."))).click()
except:
    print("If not, pass it")
    pass

try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.js-close-class"))).click()
    print('Clicked on close button if it appears')
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-testid='accept-button']"))).click()
    print('Clicked on accept cookies button')
except:
    pass

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//tr[@data-bname='Aramis Grey']//td[@data-bk='PP']"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

You can comment out this block, cause I have not seen often **Want to be kept in the loop? modal pop up.**

```
try:
    print('When we have Want to be kept in the loop? Modal pop up')
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Not Now']/.."))).click()
except:
    print("If not, pass it")
    pass
```

Also, to mention that once you click, I believe it is opening the link in new tab. if that is the case then, you'd have to switch to new tab as well :

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
```

and then you can interact with new tab items.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Unfortunately I get the error shown in the edited question.

Comment: @Andy :  Can you show us the code that you've tried when you got that error  ?

Comment: My mistake, sorry. I missed a line... doh! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The below XPath will help you to cover both criteria

```
//tr[@class='diff-row evTabRow bc' and @data-bname="Aramis Grey"]//td[@data-bk="PP"]
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this with CSS Selector you can use this locator:

```py
[class="diff-row evTabRow bc"][data-bname="Aramis Grey"] [data-bk="PP"]
```

If you prefer XPath - this locator can be used

```py
//tr[@class="diff-row evTabRow bc" and(@data-bname="Aramis Grey")]//td[@data-bk="PP"]
```

The more complete code to be used with python selenium can be something like this:

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class="diff-row evTabRow bc"][data-bname="Aramis Grey"] [data-bk="PP"]'))).click()
```

or

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//tr[@class="diff-row evTabRow bc" and(@data-bname="Aramis Grey")]//td[@data-bk="PP"]'))).click()
```

respectively.